# How can I make my website with wordpress having on-spot editing feature as compared to concrete5 CMS?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, cms

I hope you were easily able to understand my situation through the question.

1.Do we have any theme or plugin for on-spot editing the post by people or by me after the blog post is posted?

2.If there isn't any theme or pluggin for such feature should I make plugin or theme independently for my website.

3.If both of the above fails,please give me a better option for some other kind of CMS as there are no many cms and I want to make my website with dynamic features. Please follow the link below and kindly suggest me one.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is typically called *edit in place*. Try the [Front End Editor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/front-end-editor/) plugin.

Comment: Thanks milo for your answer...I thought I had to change my ideas making a website with wordpress and switch to some other CMS.Thanks a lot buddy.